# Has "na_values" been changed in python 3

Tags: python, pandas

Teaching myself python from the following [textbook](https://github.com/DataScienceUB/introduction-datascience-python-book) (which is using Python 2.7). The following snipet of code is supposed to generate a table, which is read from a csv file that I downloaded

```
edu = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/joubertd/Desktop/python_data_files/educ_figdp_1_Data.csv', na_values=':', usecols=['TIME', 'GEO', 'Value'])
edu
```

However the code above only gives me this

> Unnamed: 1    Unnamed: 2

So, I was wondering if the code for na_values changed from Python 2.7 to 3.xx

Thanks

Doug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe what you are getting is due to an issue between python 3 and 2.7. Rather I believe the csv file that you are reading does not contain a header and as a result pandas is outputting as unnamed.

Comment: Thank you so much. You were correct! I naturally assumed that the file on GitHub would be in the right format. I copied the data from the original file and it worked